# Terraform Azure hostname binding creation failing, dependencies not properly constructed

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have two Terraform modules, one which creates an Azure App Service, and another that creates a hostname binding for the App Service.

```
# Inside main.tf

# App Service

module "app_service" {
  source = "./AppService"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg_0.name
  resource_group_location = azurerm_resource_group.rg_0.location
}

# Custom Domain

module "custom_domain" {
  source = "./CustomDomain"
  base_domain = var.domain_name
  sub_domain = azurerm_resource_group.rg_0.name
  web_app = module.app_service.web_app
}
```

Inside the CustomDomain module I have the following.

```
variable "base_domain" { }
variable "sub_domain" { }
variable "web_app" { }

data "azurerm_dns_zone" "dns-zone" {
  name                = var.base_domain
}

resource "azurerm_dns_txt_record" "domain-verification" {
  name                = "asuid.${var.sub_domain}"
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 3600

  record {
    value = var.web_app.custom_domain_verification_id
  }
}

resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "cname-record" {
  name                = var.sub_domain
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.resource_group_name
  ttl                 = 3600
  record              = var.web_app.default_hostname

  depends_on = [azurerm_dns_txt_record.domain-verification]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "hostname-binding" {
  hostname            = "${var.sub_domain}.${var.base_domain}"
  app_service_name    = var.web_app.name
  resource_group_name = var.web_app.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [azurerm_dns_cname_record.cname-record]
}
```

This deployment is failing with the error

```
module.custom_domain.azurerm_dns_txt_record.domain-verification: Creating...
module.custom_domain.azurerm_dns_txt_record.domain-verification:
Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/7c34cc50-2353-4be0-bd25-d43ce1e7856e/resourceGroups/simsemsdevopsresources/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/dummy.net/TXT/asuid.tftest4-env8]
module.custom_domain.azurerm_dns_cname_record.cname-record: Creating...
module.custom_domain.azurerm_dns_cname_record.cname-record: Creation complete after 1s [id=/subscriptions/7c34cc50-2353-4be0-bd25-d43ce1e7856e/resourceGroups/simsemsdevopsresources/providers/Microsoft.Network/dnsZones/dummy.net/CNAME/tftest4-env8]
module.custom_domain.azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding.hostname-binding: Creating...
╷
│ Error: creating/updating Custom Hostname Binding "tftest4-env8.dummy.net" 
(App Service "tftest4-env8" / Resource Group "tftest4-env8"): 
web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdateHostNameBinding: Failure responding to request:
 StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 
Code="BadRequest" Message="A TXT record pointing from asuid.tftest4-env8.dummy.net to 
05334922dcaf46e4cd40398f25d5c6e96a9c1e8833b716b140eaeb06b9f838aa was not found."
```

The dependencies look correctly defined to me.

The `azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding` explicitly depends on the `azurerm_dns_cname_record`, and the `azurerm_dns_cname_record` explicitly depends on the `azurerm_dns_txt_record`.

The `azurerm_linux_web_app` is output from the AppService module and input to the CustomDomain module where `azurerm_dns_txt_record` uses `custom_domain_verification_id`

The Terraform output and the Azure portal both show that the azurerm_dns_txt_record was successfully created.

If I apply the plan a second time it succeeds.

The question is: why is this failing?

Comment: Shouldn't the AzureRm Terraform provider properly check that the resource creation has completed before signalling that it's ready?

Answer (score 0):

> terraform Azure hostname binding creation failing, dependencies not properly constructed. If I apply the plan a second time it succeeds.

The above error indicating that the terraform could not find**TXT** record. This might be due to multiple issues.

`DNS` records are not propagated globally but cached by other `Azure DNS` root servers. Due to this, it may take some time for the records to be available globally, even if they have been created successfully.

`Azure DNS` may use caching functions for both successful and unsuccessful DNS resolutions, which can cause latency in resolving newly created **DNS** records.

If you still encounter the issue, you may add time delay between creating the `TXT` record . This allows more time for `DNS` distribution to complete effectively, here is the  [time_sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) block.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      name     = "web-app-resources"
      location = "eastus"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "web-app1"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      sku_name            = "P1v2"
      os_type             = "Windows"
      depends_on = [ azurerm_resource_group.example ]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "example" {
      name                = "cxp-web-app1"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location            = azurerm_service_plan.example.location
      service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.example.id
    
      site_config {}
      depends_on = [ azurerm_service_plan.example ]
    }
    
    data "azurerm_dns_zone" "dns-zone" {
      name                = "azcxp.org"
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_dns_txt_record" "domain-verification" {
      name                = "azcxp.org"
      zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.name
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      ttl                 = 300
    
      record {
        value = azurerm_windows_web_app.example.custom_domain_verification_id
      }
    
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_dns_cname_record" "cname-record" {
      name                = "webapp.org"
      zone_name           = data.azurerm_dns_zone.dns-zone.name
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      ttl                 = 300
      record              = azurerm_windows_web_app.example.default_hostname
    
      depends_on = [azurerm_dns_txt_record.domain-verification]
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_app_service_custom_hostname_binding" "hostname-binding" {
      hostname            = "beesphotos.net"
      app_service_name    = azurerm_windows_web_app.example.name
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      depends_on = [azurerm_dns_cname_record.cname-record]
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Reference:  [azurerm_app_service_certificate_binding](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/main/website/docs/r/app_service_certificate_binding.html.markdown)